# Batch file using WinSCP won't execute UNIX shell script that assigns variables to output of "more" command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, unix

I am working with a Batch script that uses WinSCP to transfer files from an UNIX machine to a windows machine.
To achieve this, WinSCP has to call shell scripts on the UNIX side.
There is  one shell script that gets halted and doesn't return any value until the SFTP session expires without returning the expected info from the shell script.
The WinSCP line that executes this task is as follows

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /command "option batch abort" "option confirm off" "open sftp://user:password@10.111.235.132/data/line/script/" "call ./d_check_org1" "exit"
```

In this case, this line has to trigger the shell script d_check_org1 , which will show the result of its echo lines.

d_check_org1 is like this

```
#!/bin/bash

line=`more line_fullname`
seq=`more line_fullname | cut -c7-10`


if [ -d /gl/T60system/tripas/qcfiles/Line_QC/$seq ] && [ ! -z "/gl-off1/data/curro/Pi/$seq.$linefullname.*.*.pi" ]
then
Pi2name=`ls /gl-off1/data/curro/Pi2/"$seq".*| cut -c27-53`
piname=`ls /gl-off1/data/curro/Pi/"$seq".*| cut -c27-60`
echo
echo ===============================================
echo
echo DIRECTORY CHECK: 
echo              
echo For line $line   
echo              
echo $seq directory was found on qcfiles 
echo "File" $Pi2name was found on Pi2 directory 
echo "File" $piname was found on Pi directory 
echo              
echo ===============================================
else
echo
echo ===============================================
echo
echo DIRECTORY CHECK: 
echo 
echo For line $line
echo
echo $seq directory was NOT found on qcfiles, CHECK LINE NAME!
echo
echo ===============================================

fi
```

I have narrowed the problem to the first 2 lines after #!/bin/bash

If I assign a value to line and seq, then it runs and shows the contents of the echo lines

e.g. if I assign values like

```
line=2536140258
seq=0258
```

then this script will execute complete

But on its original form, where the script has to assign the name, it will stop after the connection is made until timeout.

On the UNIX side, the shell script works either way.

Note that inside the IF loop, there are 2 more variables that are assigned other values, and these 2 run perfectly, no need for a fixed value.

Comment: `more` is a paging command. It expects to be connected to a terminal of some sort. Instead, try `line=$(cat line_fullname)` & `seq=$(cat line_fullname | cut -c7-10)`. This appears to be what you want, but further on, you seem to change it from potentially multiple lines, to an expected single one. It would help to know, what exactly in `line_fullname`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What is the contents of `line_fullname` and what do you want get into variables `line` and `seq`? Is it guaranteed that the file contains exactly one line of text?

Comment: A side hint (not related to the problem): instead of all these `echo`s use two here documents. Start with `cat <<arbitrary_word`, in lines that follow place actual (possibly multi-line) stuff to be printed, terminate with a separate line containing the `arbitrary_word` only. This will feed the stuff to the `cat` and the `cat` will spit it out to stdout. In various examples `EOF` is often used for `arbitrary_word`.

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm ! Thank you very much !

Comment: For your question, linename is a file generated by another script, which is also triggered from the .bat file. It basically reads the files on the unix machine and prits the name of the last line into that file,  the batch file then gets that file and asks if you want to work on that file or on another file.

Comment: @Bib your solution worked very well, thanks a lot for that.